# SQL - How to get Top 5 record with sub-record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query that returns the following table

```
ID   SubId  Rate    Time
1    1      10.00   '00:00:10'
2    1      11.00   '00:00:15'
3    2      12.00   '00:00:20'
4    3      13.00   '00:00:25'
5    4      14.00   '00:00:30'
6    5      15.00   '00:00:35'
7    6      16.00   '00:00:40'
```

Now the problem is that i need all those record whose **SubId** lies in **Top 5 of Time's order**.

```
ID   SubId  Rate    Time
1    1      10.00   '00:00:10'
2    1      11.00   '00:00:15'
3    2      12.00   '00:00:20'
4    3      13.00   '00:00:25'
5    4      14.00   '00:00:30'
6    5      15.00   '00:00:35'
```

**My Approach**

```
Select ID,SubId,Rate from Query1 where SubId In (Select Top 5 SubId from Query1)
--Time was not included in it
```

**Note :** Please do not suggest an answer like above because it needs to use the **query twice** as the query is already taking too much time to return the above records.

Comment: Why don't you want to use the query twice.

Comment: please see the note part, it says that to produce the result it already is taking too much time

Comment: Yup, sorry. Why don't you just insert the result of that query into a temporary table and use that temp table instead. using `TOP` here might be the fastest way.

Comment: @FelixPamittan can you please post an answer to that.

Comment: Or you could use `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Query1 ORDER BY TIME DESC`.

Comment: please see the question it says it should get records according to TOP 5 SubId that means it will return 6 records

Comment: How will `SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Query1 ORDER BY TIME DESC` return 6 records?

Comment: @SouravA, no, that's not the one the OP's referring to. He wants to retrieve first the `TOP 5 SubId by TIME`. With that, `SELECT` all rows with `SubId` IN those `TOP 5`. In his case, the TOP 5's are `5,4,3,2,1`, in which 1 has two rows, `Id = 1 and Id = 2`. So, in total, there would be 6 rows.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the same query twice, I suggest you insert the result into a temporary table. That way, you don't have to execute the complex query twice.

```
CREATE TABLE #TopFive(Id)
INSERT INTO #TopFive
    SELECT TOP 5 SubId FROM QueryId ORDER BY [Time] DESC
```

Then in your subsequent queries, you can just use the temporary table:

```
SELECT * FROM <tbl> WHERE subId IN(SELECT Id FROM #TopFive)
```

You could also add a `NONCLUSTERED INDEX` on the temporary table for added performance gain:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NCI_TopFive ON #TopFive(Id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with x as 
(select row_number() over(order by time) as rn, * from tablename)
select ID,SubId,Rate from x where rn <=5
```

This will assign row numbers based on ascending order of time in your table. You can also partition and order by your desired columns. Thereafter, you can select whatever row numbers from the `cte` you need.

Comment: can you please explain how this works or what does it do?

Comment: please see there is a slight change in the question

Comment: modified the query. Also provided explanation. I have ordered by `time`. However, you can play around with that window function and modify to fit your need.

Comment: This will return only 5 records whereas the OP wanted 6 records in his output.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is only slightly different than Felix's with a small difference. I would rather create a *covered* NC Index. That way I/O operations would get reduced when it's used down the line.

Store the results once in a temporary table and create a covered non-clustered on `SubID`

```
Select ID, SubId, Rate, [Time]
INTO #results
FROM Query1


CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SubID ON #results(SubId) INCLUDE(Id, Rate, [Time])

SELECT A.ID, A.SubId, A.Rate, A.[Time]
FROM 
#results  A
JOIN
(SELECT TOP 5 SubID from #results order by [Time] desc)  B
on A.SubID  =   B.SubID
```